# How can I create my own images for multipass?

Tags: multipass

I'm having some difficulty finding docs for this.
I'd like to create my own images and use them in multipass. I can't seem to find any documentation on how to create the image (can I use a docker image, a qcow2 image?)

From what I can gather, I should be able to launch the image, once I generate it, via
multipass launch http://foo.com/images/image

with optional cloud init arguments (which I'll have to learn if I need it)

Comment: And if using an existing docker or qcow2 image isn't the answer, is there an easy way to take my existing preseed and/or Docker compose files and use those to generate an image?

Comment: Hmm...launch failed: http and file based images are not supported

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is no good way to do this, but I can use the base 20.04 image and set up a cloud-init file.